# Ubuntu on Pandaboard giving me troubles

Tags: 11.10

I'm trying to install the OMAP4 extras for ubuntu on my pandaboard. For some reason, a few packages can't seem to be agree with eachother.

This what I did so far:

- installed on Ubuntu 11.10 on sd card
- Powered on Pandaboard and let it finish it's initial install
- Did an "apt-get update" and "apt-get upgrade", to install updates

So far, everything went fine, and I was quite happy with my Pandaboard, but then I made the mistake of typing this:

apt-get install ubuntu-imap4-extras

At first, everything seemed ok, and it started downloading and installing. But then after a while it just crashed. I tried it again but then it gave me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-omap4-extras is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gstreamer0.10-openmax : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad but it is not going to be installed
gstreamer0.10-plugin-ducati : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad but it is not going to be installed
ubuntu-omap4-extras-multimedia : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad (>= 0.10.22-2ubuntu4+ti1.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I tried to the suggestion: apt-get -f install:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
The following NEW packages will be installed:
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
88 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,794 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,571 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 143575 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad (from .../gstreamer0.10-plugins bad_0.10.22-2ubuntu4+ti1.5.4.8+1_armel.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad_0.10.22-2ubuntu4+ti1.5.4.8+1_armel.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libgstbasecamerabinsrc-0.10.so.0.0.0', which is also in package gstreamer0.10-plugins-good 0.10.30-1ubuntu7.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad_0.10.22-2ubuntu4+ti1.5.4.8+1_armel.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Seems like two packages (plugins-good and plugins-bad) are fighting over the same library.

Any idea on how to fix this??

Answer (score 2):

My steps to solve this problem:

```
dpkg -r --force all gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
apt-get -f install
apt-get install ubuntu-omap4-extras
```

Force to remove the good package first!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to clean and update your system

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```